# Get penultimate values from pandas group by

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tail

I want to groupby pandas dataframe and get last n elements from each group but with any offset. For example, after group by column A i've a column 'A' with elements in column 'B' with values (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) for certain value in 'A'. And I want to take the last 10 elements excluding the most recent one or two. How can I do it?
I've tried to use tail(), `df.groupby('A').tail(10)`, but that's not my case.

input: 'A': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,], 'B': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] output: (last 3 excluding the recent 2) 'A' [1], 'B': [5,6,7]

Comment: Could you provide an input/output example please?

Comment: input: 'A': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,], 'B': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
output: (last 3 excluding the recent 2) 'A' [1], 'B': [5,6,7]

Comment: Please can you [edit] that into your question?

Comment: Maybe this can help you:
`df.groupby('A').shift(-2).tail(10).reset_index().unique()`

Comment: @VladislavaGonchar, When I do shift, I get dataframe, which's not grouped by, and tail doesn't work correctly

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is unusual task, since all your "A" values are the same -> it is weird to group by such a column.

This leads to 2 solutions that came to my mind...

1]

```
data = {'A': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 'B': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]}
df_dict = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
no_of_unwanted_values = 2
df_dict.groupby('A').agg(lambda a: a).head(-no_of_unwanted_values)#.tail(1)
```

This solution work if you group by A-column-row-specific values. The head(-x) selects all the values top down but the last x values.

I think what you are looking for is the second solution:

2]

```
data = {'A': [1,2,1,3,1,2,1,2,3], 'B': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]}
df_dict = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data) 
no_of_unwanted_values = 2
df_dict.groupby('A').sum().head(-no_of_unwanted_values)#.tail(1)
```

Here you have 3 values to group by and then you are using some operation on those groups (in this case it is sum). Lastly you select again all but the last with head(-x). Optionaly if you would like to select also some values but the top ones from such set, you can append the query by .tail() and again specify number of rows to retrieve. The last line could be also rewriten as len(df_dict) - no_of_unwanted_values (but in this case the number of unwanted values woudl have to be x + 1). You could apply the logic with len(x) - 1 for example also to selection of lists.

PS.:
beware when using sort_values for example:

```
data.sort_values(['col_1','col_2']).groupby('col_3','col_2').head(x)
```

here the head(x) correspond to col_1 values. That is if you want all but last values for len(data.col_1.unique()) = 100, use head(99).